# C# application that will automate the drag of an image into the Compose box of Gmail

Tags: c#, browser, console

I need to write a console application that will constantly look to see if the Compose window of Gmail is open in a tab in pretty much any browser.  If the console app sees that the Compose window is open (by checking if the url of the tab is: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#compose) it will then "drag and drop" a file into the Compose box.  Any clue on how to go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: It really sounds like this should be solved differently. Please explain **what** you want to do, not **how** you think it should be done.

Comment: It is very possible that this could be solved differently.  The goal of the project is to emulate and automate how Gmail embeds images in an email when you drag and drop an image from your desktop so that when the user is on the Compose screen an image based template is automatically placed inside the Compose box.  When the image is dragged and dropped it is essentially uploaded to Gmail's servers and embedded.  The alternative we have is linking out to an image via a url, but the image does not get embedded the same way it does if it is drag/drop.  The embedding is the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a tab in Google Chrome via

```
Process.Start("%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", 
          "http:\\www.YourUrl.com");
```

Then you can be sure that, in your case `mail.google.com` is opened.

Take a look at the WatiN Framework.

With that you can get all elements on the webpage.
You can also move your mouse to that element:

http://khemlall.info/2011/07/21/how-to-move-mouse-hover-over-obout-controls-using-watin-framework/

Then you can emulate a mouse move with

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

Comment: I have used Watin in the past to open browsers and perform certain actions.  The scenario I have here is that my application cannot control the opening of the browser.  The drag/drop should only fire if the user happens to navigate to Compose in Gmail.  Am I missing something that Watin now does?  I'll take a look at emulating a mouse move, thanks.